# Personalizar Menú ToolBar Android

Tags: android, menú

Saludos.

He creado una toolbar y un menú para mostrar los íconos de las redes sociales. Quisiera alinearlos junto al margen inferior del logo de la app y no lo logro.

Ni programando en java ni aplicando propiedades en el XML.

Será que debo crear una customView? Esto lo hice pero sin mucho éxito.

Este es mi código.

Activity.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fbef04"
        android:id="@+id/appBar">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:logo="@drawable/ic_logo_sin_pagina"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/principalLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Menú

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/instagram_item"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/instagram_logo"
    android:title="Instagram" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/facebook_item"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/facebook_logo_png_transparent_background"
    android:title="Facebook" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/twitter_item"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/twittericon"
    android:title="Twitter" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/googleplus_item"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/gp"
    android:title="Google Plus"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
private EnVivoFragment enVivoFragmentCaracas;
private EnVivoFragment enVivoFragmentMiami;
private OnDemandFragment onDemandFragment;
private Fragment selectedFragment;
private FragmentManager FM;
private FragmentTransaction FT;
private BottomBar bottomBar;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
Bundle globalSavedInstanceState;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    globalSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    //Renderizando el Layout de la toolbar
    appBarLayout = new AppBarLayout(this);
    appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBar);

    //Renderizando los dos layouts de la actividad
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.three_buttons_activity);


    //Renderizando la toolbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
    toolbar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    //Creando el ViewTreeObserver de la appBarLayout para usar en el método más abajo.
    final AppBarLayout fullScreenLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = fullScreenLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

    /**
     * Este método obtiene las medidas de los Layouts durante el proceso de creación.
     * Para conservarlos, cualquier cálculo que quiera realizar con ellos deeben ser realizados
     * aquí dentro.
     */
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //remove listener to ensure only one call is made.
            fullScreenLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            int h = fullScreenLayout.getHeight();
            int w = fullScreenLayout.getWidth();

            onDemandFragment = new OnDemandFragment();
            selectedFragment = new Fragment();
            enVivoFragmentCaracas = EnVivoFragment.newInstance(h, "Caracas");//Para poder pasar la altura de la actionBar.
            enVivoFragmentMiami = EnVivoFragment.newInstance(h, "Miami");//Para poder pasar la altura de la actionBar.
            createBottomBar(enVivoFragmentCaracas, enVivoFragmentMiami, onDemandFragment, globalSavedInstanceState);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.redes_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Esconde la BottomBar.
 */
public void hideBottomBar() {
    bottomBar.hide();
}

/**
 * Muestra la BottomBar.
 */
public void showBottomBar() {
    bottomBar.show();
}

/**
 * Esconde la ActionBar/Toolbar.
 */
public void hideActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

/**
 * Muestra la ActionBar/ToolBar.
 */
public void showActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().show();
}

/**
 * Esconde la NAvigationBar del SO.
 * Depende de las versiones del API.
 */
public void hideNavigationBar() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
    // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
    // a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
    // hide the navigation bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}

/**
 * Muestra la NavigationBa del SO.
 * Depende de las versiones del API.
 */
public void showNavigationBar() {
    // set navigation bar status, remember to disable "setNavigationBarTintEnabled"
    final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    // This work only for android 4.4+
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

        // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
        // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
        // show up and won't hide
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Renderiza y agrega la BottomBar a la activity. Al mismo tiempo anexa y maneja los fragments
 * en un case que asigna el Fragment a la pantalla de acuerdo a la selección del usuario.
 *
 * @param enVivoFragmentCaracas Fragment del tipo EnVivo.
 * @param enVivoFragmentMiami   Fragment tipo EnVivo con URL Miami.
 * @param onDemandFragment      Fragment del tipo OnDeand.
 * @param savedInstanceState    Estado global de la actividad.
 */
public void createBottomBar(final EnVivoFragment enVivoFragmentCaracas, final EnVivoFragment enVivoFragmentMiami, final OnDemandFragment onDemandFragment, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FT = FM.beginTransaction();

    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, ManageParrilla.getProgramaAlAire(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    FT.add(R.id.principalLayout, enVivoFragmentCaracas).commit();

    bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.botton_bar_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.envivoCaracas_item:
                    selectedFragment = enVivoFragmentCaracas;
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, ManageParrilla.getProgramaAlAire(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.envivoMiami_item:
                    selectedFragment = enVivoFragmentMiami;
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "EN Vivo! ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.onDemand_item:
                    selectedFragment = onDemandFragment;
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "On Demand", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
            FT = FM.beginTransaction();
            FT.replace(R.id.principalLayout, selectedFragment).commit();
        }
    });


    // Set the color for the active tab. Ignored on mobile when there are more than three tabs.
    bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#FF4CAF50");

    // Use the dark theme. Ignored on mobile when there are more than three tabs.
    bottomBar.useDarkTheme(true);

    // Use custom text appearance in tab titles.
    //bottomBar.setTextAppearance(R.style.MyTextAppearance);

    // Use custom typeface that's located at the "/src/main/assets" directory. If using with
    // custom text appearance, set the text appearance first.
    //bottomBar.setTypeFace("MyFont.ttf");

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.instagram_item) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.facebook_item) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.twitter_item) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.googleplus_item) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Haga lo que haga, los íconos del menú no bajan, como aparece en la imagen. Tampoco puedo poner un color de fondo a la parte donde están los botones.

Hay forma de hacer eso?

Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te sugiero que la app la construyas siguiendo la guia de estilo en Material Design, muchos aspectos de funcionalidad los tiene integrados.

Comment: Yo no agregaría los iconos al Menu, agregaria una vista sobre el toolbar y dentro pondría los iconos para poder alinearlos como lo necesitas.

Comment: Saludos @Bourne gracias por tu respuesta. Entonces no utilizo menú?.

Comment: Saludos @KarolynMéndez, desde mi punto de vista no es necesario, puedes poner los iconos dentro de tu layout.

Answer (score 1):

La manera mas fácil de agregar los iconos es manejarlos de otra forma que no sea un menú, como imágenes separadas o layouts. Te dejo un ejemplo de un toolbar con los elementos alineados.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        tools:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        tools:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/firma_title"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_save"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Asi queda, ya nadamas cambias los iconos por los de tus redes sociales

[image: Ejemplo toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

Sera dificil lograr que los iconos esten alineados al logo de la applicacion, ya que los iconos los estas agregando como elementos del menu.

Si tienes un **[Toolbar](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar)**, una de las ventajas es que puedes agregar un layout que pueda contener todos los elementos y de esta forma podrias alinearlos.

Comment: Hola @Elenasys Muchas gracias por responder! Lo intentaré. Una sola duda. El logo debe quedar fuera de dicho layout?. Saludos.

Comment: El layout puede contener incluso el Icono, es como una especie de ActionBar personalizado.